# Invalid value for ByteString on updating user photo in google admin-sdk

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

Hello I have created node project in which I am trying to update user photo in G-suite using admin-sdk/directory API
I am passing base64 image from postman and converting it to web-safe base64 bytedata

```
req.body.photoData.replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\=/g, '*')
```

above regex will replace string as per the google doc for photo bytedata
but I am getting bad request of Invalid value for ByteString

I a following this doc

> https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/photos

suggest me if anyone have answer of it.

Answer (score 0):

U dont need to replace the `=` character, just replace `/` and `+`.